# Different semantics of KProperty1<T, R> in JS compared to JVM

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js-interop, kotlin-multiplatform

It looks like `KProperty1<T, R>` has different semantics in JVM and JS e.g. while this test works on the JVM:

```
data class Data(val name: String)
class Test {
    @Test fun propertiesMustBeEqual() {
        assertEquals(Data::name, Data::name)
    }
}
```

it fails in Javascript with this message:

```
1) test
       Test
         propertiesMustBeEqual:
     AssertionError: Expected <function ($receiver) {
      return $receiver.name;
    }>, actual <function ($receiver) {
      return $receiver.name;
    }>
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation of `KProperty` that requires this equality, as such this test is invalid. It's trying to test undocumented behavior. Why are you trying to test it?

Comment: Very simplified, I was trying to construct a map of functions to be applied to certain properties like `Map<KProperty<Data, Any>, List<(Any) -> Boolean>>` and later lookup the list of functions by indexing with the property-instance. Since I stayed purely in Kotlin for that, I would have expected JVM and JS to behave the same. So imo either the JVM should create new distinct `KProperty` instances on every invocation of e.g. `Data::name` or JS should yield the same instance on the invocations.

Comment: I agree that would make it consistent, but there is nothing in the documentation that tells you that it can behave either way. So, either way is correct. You cannot rely on it implementing `equals` and `hashCode` properly. I think that would be _useful_, but it's not the case right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbound property references to the same property should be equal on all platforms. But the situation that they aren't equal in JS is a bug tracked as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15101